# VS Code Server's github signin going to 127.0.0.1

Tags: vscode-remote

I'm trying to setup a VS Code server with an apache proxy, and authentication, but when trying to sign into Github, it redirects to 127.0.0.1

I've tried setting http.proxy to my url, and fiddling with apache proxy settings